# Xcode SpriteKit: How to add a Sprite Atlas in Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, xcode13

I just watched an old tutorial of xcode where a "Sprite Atlas" added.
But by me in Xcode 13 the option to add a sprite atlas is missing.
Does somebody know how I can add a sprite atlas into my assets folder in xcode 13?

I would be very happy to hear from you!
Best regards

Comment: Edit your question by adding a link to the tutorial you're folliowing, the steps you take to add the sprite atlas, what you expect to see, and what you see. Adding this information will make it easier for someone to answer your question.

Comment: Click on 'Create asset catalogs and sets' at the following URL to see if that helps.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktextureatlas/about_texture_atlases

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer! I don't have a link to the tutorial because the tutorial is from Udemy. I followed the ducumentation of apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktextureatlas/about_texture_atlases and there is a line where it is written: **You create a sprite atlas using Xcode. First add a new asset catalog to your project; see Add files and folders to a project. Then, inside the new asset catalog, add a new sprite atlas.** but i don't know how to add a sprite atlas into my asset catalog.

Comment: [This is an older post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49866298/4376309) and I'm not currently fresh enough on SpriteKit to update it. But it may still be relevant to you.

Answer (score 2):

`New Sprite Atlas` option can be found under `AR and Textures` in Xcode 13.

In Assets.xcassets, click `+` icon (or right click at the space under `AppIcon`) and then `AR and Textures` > `New Sprite Atlas`