# watchOS - SpriteKit app getting killed because of too much CPU Usage

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, watchos

My problem happens on watchOS, but i guess it's a general SpriteKit question
so... I have a watchOS app that is rendering a SpriteKit scene (basically a custom MapView). When my user is panning on the watch, I update my SpriteKit's position and when the user turns the crown, I update it's scale.

So now when the user is going really mad and panning and zooming like crazy, my scene will have to update quite often which will then lead to a "crash" with the reason that I exceeded the CPU limits.

```
e.g.:
CPU: 9 seconds cpu time over 20 seconds (46% cpu average), exceeding limit of 15% cpu over 60 seconds
```

When sprit-nodes go off screen I already cache them (and reuse them when I might need them again, instead of just removing them) which is making things better, but still if no sprite is ever re-used, CPU usage is going up again.
Most time is spent here:

```
let texture = SKTexture(image: image)
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
```

How would you deal with that? Throttle user-input after a while? Or is there any Info.plist check that I didn't find yet telling watchOS that it's fine if my app uses a bit more?

Comment: Maybe try and “debounce” a little

Comment: I did that now, yes... I throttled update calls to around 10fps... and that's fine enough for my usecase. I am also not sure it it's the SwiftUI wrapper that might cause problems. Will have to debug that a bit more... Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

This instruction

```
let texture = SKTexture(image: image)
```

is expensive because as [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktexture/texture_initializers#1654213) states:

> The image data is copied before control is returned to your game.

## TextureAtlas

Instead you should leverage a `TextureAtlas` this way

```
guard
    let enemyImage = UIImage(named: "panda.png"),
    let heroImage = UIImage(named: "hero.png")
else {
    fatalError()
}
let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(dictionary: ["enemy": pandaImage,
                                               "hero": heroImage])
```

Next when you need to instantiate a Sprite using a specific texture you write

```
guard let heroTexture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("hero") else { fatalError() }
let hero = SKSpriteNode(texture: heroTexture)
```

## Generate TextureAtlas statically

You can also let Xcode populate the TextureAtlas for you following [these instructions](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev0bfaf1ab7).

## Sprite Atlas

Or, you can switch to the more modern SpriteAtlas technique following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866311/1761687).

## Notes

Of course replace the `fatalError()` with a more suitable error management.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! The thing is that my SpriteKit app ist not a game, but a mapview (the on from apple does now allow custom tiles on watchOS), where I load the content of each sprite on the fly. I already implemented some more caching, which reduced the time spent quite a bit. But any further tips with that additional information, would be very welcome of course!!! Again, thanks a lot for your detailed answer!